# Notify admin via email when order is placed in magento

Tags: magento, admin

Is there a way to Notify admin via email when order is placed in magento? I feel like this is a silly question but I'm placing test orders currently and I'm not getting any email notification.

Will the order also get an email notification by default or does the admin have to click the "invoice button" each time an order comes in?

Comment: could you please mark the answer correct, this will help

Answer (score 26):

In the magento backend goto

```
System > Configuration
```

**`Left Naviagation > Sales > Sales Emails`**  this option will let you configure mail sending settings where you can ask magento to send you mail whenever an order is placed.

Alternatively, you can create a plugin with an observer which listens to the event of the order being placed and you can write your mail sending code in the observer.

Comment: That's right. The first solution allow to send copy or bcc email of the customer's order email (the same option exists for invoice, shipment and creditmemo). The second one will allow to send custom mail.

Answer (score 0):

Once configured...

Are you sure that email is being sent?

```
<?php
 $to = "recipient@example.com";
 $subject = "Hi!";
 $body = "Hi,\n\nHow are you?";
 if (mail($to, $subject, $body)) {
   echo("sent!");
  } else {
   echo("failed");
  }
?>
```

also check your /var/log/maillog for messages.

Answer (score 0):

Go to System -> Configuration -> Select Store email addresses and change the Sales representative's email address.

Then go to Left Naviagation > Sales > Sales Emails and ensure that it is set for Sales representative.

Also just check that you've done this on the main site.